# load dynamic library c++ for windows

Tags: c++, windows, dynamic-library

I have to edit a c++ Linux code on a Windows platform. I'm using Visual Studio. This c++ code calls a jar to use JNI. The problem is that under Windows calling JNI is a bit more complicated than under Linux. So I have to load the jvm.dll in the code. I'm a bit noob in C++, I've searched a lot, tried a lot, but found nothing that I can make work. So I would need help to load manually a dll please.

Comment: Look up `GetProcAddress` and `LoadLibrary` if you really need manual dll loading at runtime. Otherwise consider static linking with an import library.

Comment: Finally it's OK. I've used LoadLibrary() with the path of the dll. Be careful to use "\\" for the path separator, or it won't work